# LUIS App Settings - Endpoint Key Assigned

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

How could I assign a LUIS generated subscription key through Azure Portal to my LUIS model if I'm not using the same credentials for both portals?

In the case of Bing Spell Check I can add it manually but in the case of LUIS not.

[image: LUIS Portal]

Answer (score 0):

Well,with the Luis' Web developing,the function about azure subkey is already here,yet I hadn't test it.